# Sum of Binomial Coefficients over a specific range of values of $K$ and fixed value of $N$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I am stuck in a problem where for e.g., - I am calculating here $~^{10}C_4 + ^{10}C_6 + ^{10}C_8~$ where $~N~$ is same $(10$ in this example$)$ and $K$ is varying with difference of $2~($Odd or even indexed$)$, Here I have to individually calculate the Binomial Coefficient of each and then sum them up. Is there any formula that I can directly apply to achieve the same where I just need to put the range $([4-8]$ in the above example$)$ and get the result.

Key Points -

$ 1. ~~ N~~ $is Fixed 
$ 2.~~ K~~$ is varying with difference of $2~ ($ It can be odd
    indexed like $~^{10}C_3+^{10}C_5+^{10}C_7~$ or even indexed like $~^{10}C_2+ ^{10}C_4 +
^{10}C_6+\cdots~)$
 
 $3.~~ K~~$ can start and end anywhere between $0$ to $N$.

Hope I am clear. Thanks in advance. Any help would be very nice.

Comment: You have that $(1+x)^{N}=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{N}{k}x^k$. Then $(1-x)^{N}=\sum_{k=0}^{N}(-1)^k\binom{N}{k}x^k$. If you sum both, the terms with $k$ odd cancel and the terms with $k$ even get doubled. If the sum doesn't add all terms from $0$ to $N$, then the problem is more complicated. It depends on what terms are exactly being added.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I know that it will be equal to 2 raise to power n-1 but it would be when K starts from 0 and ends at N, but in my question k can start and end anywhere between 0 and N . Pardon my mathematical notations here, new at Stack Exchange.

Comment: By using $\binom{N}{k} = \binom{N-1}{k-1}+\binom{N-1}{k}$, you can convert this into a similar question where $k$ varies with a difference of $1$ (that is, you are adding up some range of binomial coefficients). [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17202/sum-of-the-first-k-binomial-coefficients-for-fixed-n) provides more information; it seems unlikely that there is a simple closed form; one of the answers gives a non-elementary closed form.